# How to detect with PhoneGap on iOS if call is made or not

Tags: ios, cordova, call

When using the telprompt intent on iOS like

```
window.location = 'telprompt://' + phoneNumber
```

the user gets prompted to either call the number or cancel.
Is there a way to know which of the two actions the user has made?

Looking at the PhoneGap docs the "startcallbutton" event is only supported on BlackBerry.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

All you can do is listen for the pause event.

```
document.addEventListener("pause", yourCallbackFunction, false);
```

This event will be fired when there is an incoming call or starting a call.

or you could look into the phone listener plugin and try to write it for iOS
https://github.com/devgeeks/PhoneListener

Comment: The "pause" event is a workaround but not accurate since the user could also have pressed the home button. Seems like it's required to write an iOS plugin or wait for PhoneGap to expose this event.

Comment: I think this is the only event that is going to be used. Many people have asked on the phonegap google group and thats what I found.